# Downloading the files(which are uploaded) from media folder in django 1.4.3

Tags: python, django, file, download, media

I am using django to design the basic web pages that handles the `uploading` and `downloading` of the files to/from the `media` folder

Actually the files are uploaded successfully in to the media folder, also files are downloaded successfully but an `underscore` is appended to the file_name as a `last charater` like  `file_one.pdf_` , `file_two.pdf_` , `file_three.txt_`  etc.,

Below are my codes

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
             url(r'^upload$', 'learn_django.views.upload'),
             url(r'^files_list$', 'learn_django.views.files_list'),
             url(r'^download/(?P<file_name>.+)$', 'learn_django.views.download'),
)
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',{'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),
) + urlpatterns
```

**views.py**

```
def upload(request):
    ......
    ....
    return render_to_response('uploads_form.html', {'form': form},context_instance=RequestContext(request))


def files_list(request):
    return render_to_response('files_list.html',{'total_files':os.listdir(settings.MEDIA_ROOT),'path':settings.MEDIA_ROOT},context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def download(request,file_name):
    file_path = settings.MEDIA_ROOT +'/'+ file_name
    file_wrapper = FileWrapper(file(file_path,'rb'))
    file_mimetype = mimetypes.guess_type(file_path)
    response = HttpResponse(file_wrapper, content_type=file_mimetype )
    response['X-Sendfile'] = file_path
    response['Content-Length'] = os.stat(file_path).st_size
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s/' % smart_str(file_name) 
    return response
```

**files_list.html**

```
<table border="1" colspan="2" width="100%">
   <tr>
     <th width="60%">File</td>
     <th width="40%">Download</td> 
   </tr>
 {% for file in total_files %}
   <tr>
     <td width="60%">{{file}}</td>
     <td width="40%" align="center"><a href="/download/{{file}}" style="text-decoration:None">Download here</a></td>
   </tr>
 {% endfor %}  
</table>
```

So in the above codes, when a file is uploaded successfully in to media , it will be redirected to `files_list.html` through `files_list` view functions which displays the total number of files in the form of table with a download link beside to each file name.

So when we click on the download anchor link the appropriate file will be downloaded by executing the function `download` .

So the file is downloading sucessfully , but an `underscore` `_` is appending to the last of the file name like `file_one.pdf_` , `file_two.pdf_` , `file_three.txt_`  etc.,.

So can anyone please let me know, what's wrong in my above download function code and why `underscore` is appending to the `file name` and how to remove that `underscore` from the file name...

Answer (score 6):

Just remove `/` after filename.

Change this:

```
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s/' % smart_str(file_name)
```

to this:

```
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % smart_str(file_name)
```

Answer (score 6):

Your code is right but there is one redundant character in `download`:

```
def download(request,file_name):
    file_path = settings.MEDIA_ROOT +'/'+ file_name
    file_wrapper = FileWrapper(file(file_path,'rb'))
    file_mimetype = mimetypes.guess_type(file_path)
    response = HttpResponse(file_wrapper, content_type=file_mimetype )
    response['X-Sendfile'] = file_path
    response['Content-Length'] = os.stat(file_path).st_size
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s/' % smart_str(file_name) 
    return response
```

At last line the filename attribute has a trailing slash (/): `filename=%s`**/**

Which causes the problem. Remove this slash and it works.

Answer (score 2):

These are all not required.In HTML you can download the media file by using `<a download="{video.URL}">`

For example:

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-info">
<a href="{{result.products.full_video.url}}" download="{{result.products.full_video.url}}" style="text-decoration:None" class="footer_link">Download<i class="fa fa-download"></i></a>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by replacing

```
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=diploma_"' + str(someID) + '.pdf"'
```

with

```
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="diploma_{}{}"'.format(str(someID),'.pdf')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import urllib, mimetypes
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404, StreamingHttpResponse, FileResponse
import os
from django.conf import settings
from wsgiref.util import FileWrapper

class DownloadFileView(django_views):
    def get(self,request,file_name):
        file_path = settings.MEDIA_ROOT +'/'+ file_name
        file_wrapper = FileWrapper(open(file_path,'rb'))
        file_mimetype = mimetypes.guess_type(file_path)
        response = HttpResponse(file_wrapper, content_type=file_mimetype )
        response['X-Sendfile'] = file_path
        response['Content-Length'] = os.stat(file_path).st_size
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s/' % str(file_name) 
        return response
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Code-only answers are not particularly helpful. Please include a brief description of how this code solves the problem.